# Bayesina estimator for a discrete-valued parameter and posterior pdf of the parameter.

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution, estimation, bayesian

A discrete-valued parameter with the prior pdf
$$
p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{2}p_i\delta(x-1)
$$
is measured with the additive noise $w \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$
$$
Z = X + W
$$

The above is the initial statements of a question from chapter 2 of the book [Estimation with Applications to Tracking and Navigation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047141655X).

There is one item that asks for the posterior pdf of the parameter, and here is what I did:

$$
\begin{aligned}
p_{X|Z}(x|z) &= \frac{p_{X,Z}(x,z)}{p_Z(z)} \\
             &= \frac{p_{Z|X}(z|x)p_X(x)}{p_Z(z)} \\
             &= \frac{p_{Z|X}(z|x)p_X(x)}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p_{X,Z}(x,z)dx} \\
             &= \frac{p_{Z|X}(z|x)p_X(x)}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p_{Z|X}(z|x)p_X(x)dx}.
\end{aligned}
$$

---

PROBABLY THE FOLLOWING IS WRONG. SE EDITED PART!!!

Well $p_X(x)$ is given and $p_{Z|X}(z|x)$ is the convolution 
$$
\begin{aligned}
(p_X(x) * p_W(w))(z) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p_X(x)p_W(t-x)dx \\
                     &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p_X(t-w)p_W(w)dw.
\end{aligned}
$$

---

With the exposed, I would like to address three questions. Fisrt: Are these steps corrects? Second: If yes, how can I compute the convolution between a continuous and discrete random variables. Third: what would be the posterios pdf of the parameter.

**Edited:**

I Think that the convolution statement is wrong, because the convolution of the sum between $X$ and $W$ pdfs is $p_Z(z)$ and not $p_Z(z|x)$. So, other question, how can I compute the conditional pdf $P_Z(z|x)$??

Well $p_X(x)$ is given and $p_{Z|X}(z|x)$ is the convolution 
$$
\begin{aligned}
(p_X(x) * p_W(w))(z) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p_X(x)p_W(t-x)dx \\
                     &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p_X(t-w)p_W(w)dw.
\end{aligned}
$$